# How to sort the 2D array?

Tags: c++, matrix

So basically this program sorts the elements of the rows of the 2D array in increasing order. Basically we have written this program in class and I don't really understand how it works to be honest also I tries to run it and it does not work. I wanna understand what's wrong with the program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
bool func(int *, int);

int main() {
    int **a, i, j, m, n, **b, x, *g, y;
    cin >> n >> m;

    // initializes new array

    a = new int *[m];
    assert(a);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        a[i] = new int [n];
        assert (a[i]);
    }

    // the same here

    b = new int *[m];
    assert (b);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        b[i] = func(a[i], n);

    // swaps the elements

    for (i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < m; j++)
            if(b[i] > b[j]) {
                x = b[i];
                b[i] = b[j];
                b[j] = x;

                y = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = y;
            }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j< n; j++)
            cout << a[i][j];
            cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        delete [] a[i];
        delete [] a;
        delete [] b;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a new function that compares finds the maximum of the elements

```cpp
int func (int *a, int n) {
    int i, max = a[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Hint : [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: It uses [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: I see a cotradiction between "this program sorts the elements of the rows of the 2D array in increasing order" and "it does not work". Could you clarify?

Comment: What makes you think that "it does not work"? What have you observed? For which input? What did you expect instead? Did you observe anything helpful via a debugger?

Comment: The way you delete the array `a` abd `b` at the end of main is clearly incorrect. Every `new[]` must be matched with a `delete[]` and that clearly isn't happening in this code.

Comment: `new` never returns NULL (it throws an exception on failure), so all those asserts are redundent.

Comment: `a` is unitialised, I'm not sure how you are expecting to sort values that are unspecified.

Comment: `func` is an array returning an `int` but it is being assigned to `b[i]` which is an `int` pointer. Similar error exists in multiple places, you seem unsure if `b` is a 1D or 2D array.

Comment: The code is actually worthless, and you should start again. The strange thing is that you don't properly explain what it means to sort a 2D array. It's certainly not obvious what that means. You say increasing order, but increasing order of what? If you aren't clear about the problem in your own mind then you really have zero chance of writing a program to solve the problem.